# I get RangeError (index) error when I change data of firebasefirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

`The following RangeError was thrown building: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1`

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .where("tuid", isEqualTo: teacher)
            .where('role', isEqualTo: 'student')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("something is wrong");
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }

          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: kOtherColor,
              borderRadius: kTopBorderRadius,
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                  return Slidable(
                    endActionPane:
                        ActionPane(motion: const DrawerMotion(), children: [
                      SlidableAction(
                        onPressed: (context) => {
                          acceptPayment(
                              snapshot.data!.docChanges[index].doc['uid']),
                        },
                        label: 'Accept',
                        icon: Icons.check,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      ),
                      SlidableAction(
                        onPressed: (context) => {
                          rejectPayment(
                              snapshot.data!.docChanges[index].doc['uid']),
                        },
                        label: 'Reject',
                        icon: Icons.close,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      )
                    ]),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: kOtherColor,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Align(
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Text(
                                              snapshot.data!.docChanges[index]
                                                  .doc['email'],
                                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .textTheme
                                                  .subtitle2!
                                                  .copyWith(
                                                    color: kTextBlackColor,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                                  ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      if (snapshot.data!.docChanges[index]
                                              .doc['payment status'] ==
                                          'paid')
                                        IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.check_circle_outline))
                                      else if (snapshot.data!.docChanges[index]
                                              .doc['payment status'] ==
                                          'rejected')
                                        IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.close_outlined))
                                      else if (snapshot.data!.docChanges[index]
                                              .doc['payment status'] ==
                                          'submitted')
                                        IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () {},
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.circle_outlined)),
                                      IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (snapshot.data!.docChanges[index]
                                                  .doc['payment image'] !=
                                              '') {
                                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (_) => ShowImage(
                                                  imageUrl: snapshot
                                                      .data!
                                                      .docChanges[index]
                                                      .doc['payment image'],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          } else {
                                            showSnackBar('No Payment Image',
                                                Duration(seconds: 2));
                                          }
                                        },
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.image),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          );
        },
      ),
```

```
  Future acceptPayment(String uid) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .update({'payment status': 'paid'});
  }

  Future rejectPayment(String uid) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .update({'payment status': 'rejected'});
  }
```

My screen is StatefulWidget. I get error when i press on accept or reject icon.

I think problem is when I press icon of accept or reject. Data has change in firebase but list bulider length change fix for that range.

I want change icon of payment when I press accept or reject and data also has been change on firebase.